# flash builder 4 - annoying error message while "validating server configuration"

Tags: eclipse, configuration, flash-builder

As I haven't yet streamlined my configuration/project management yet, I keep reorganizing the project structure and workspace. Similarly I keep changing **apache's webroot**. Every time I change it, I go and change the **server location** in flex server settings. And ever time, I validate it throws error.

> c:\somepath\wwwroot is not a valid location because the project contains a linked resource
>   at that location

Randomly I resolved it which I don't know/remember the step (mostly by deleting the metadata stuff).

Can anyone tell me what this linked resource FB4 is looking at and how to get rid of it?

**Edit:**

It seems like the bin-debug is a linked to the folder (so called linked resource) which is also the output path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that flash builder has problem to accept the webroot and output folder to be same. So what I did is I changed the output folder to a subdirectory. (in my case it is /flash

This solved the problem and also some other annoying problem which was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351179/flex-4-with-php-and-bulkloader-assets-getting-deleted)