# Flex 4 with PHP and BulkLoader - Assets getting deleted

Tags: flex4, loader, wampserver, bulkloader

Has anyone ever encountered a situation where your assets (image png files) got deleted from your web path?

Let me explain it little more clearly.

I am loading some images located in my localhost (not in flex4 application path) from my flex4 application using the loader and also with [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/)

This is the second time it happened that some of the images got deleted from the path which are in localhost.

I am not sure what is causing this? is that the loader? or bulkloader or the webserver? (WAMP) or any virus?

It happened 2nd time in last 7 days. I was lucky that I had a copy in the remote host so I got them back easily. But its a mistrey what and why it is getting deleted.

Any thoughts what might have caused this? or anyone knows any bug in the Loader or BulkLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer. The **culprit** is the Flash Builder.

I am prity sure many of flash developers have faced the debugger launching issue where the flash builder never launches the app as it might have struck up some where and it halts the launching process at around 50-60% progress. It happened to me too and happens considerable enough times in a day.

I just found that this is linked to the issue which I have asked.

FB cleans the debug/output folder every time the app is compiled. I wouldn't have mind if it cleans only the project files. However, it just removes all the contents in the folder and adds them back. This happens in the back ground every time I change the code and save and run or "Clean" the project to build a fresh copy.

During this process (removing and adding files back) if the FB struck up and I forcefully terminate the process (which is must some times); my files are gone.

The **flash output folder** is **my web root** where I will have all my php, assets and all server-side stuff.

I will open a topic to discuss on how to avoid it which also I have problem there too.

Comment: You can avoid this by putting all of your static assets in the "html template" folder in your project (in Flash Builder).  Flash Builder will recreate the "bin-debug" and "bin-release" directories using the HTML template.